# Calculating the duration of a task according to other tasks

Tags: ms-project

I am using C# COM-Interop to automate the creation of a MS-Project file.

After the creation of the MS-Project file, I create some indented tasks that receive by a web service.

```
Test1 duration=? startDate=?
|-Test2 duration="1 day" startDate="02/08/17"
|-Test3 duration=? startDate=?
|--Test4 duration="3 day" startDate="03/08/17"
|--Test5 duration="2 day" startDate="05/08/17"
|-Test6 duration=? startDate=?
|--Test5 duration="1 day" startDate="08/08/17"
```

For each main task of the file, I want to calculate the duration and the start date of a task according to the tasks that are under it. But I don't know what kind of properties I can use to do so.

Comment: What Com-Interop's are you using? Which assemblies? What are they doing exactly? Creatíng an MS-Project-File? So you've got a program that creates a C#-Project to measure how long a task takes? Why?

Comment: I added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start and Finish dates of Summary tasks are calculated automatically; you do not need to calculate the duration or Start/Finish dates of a Summary task.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it made me able to figure out a solution !